# Adaptive subtraction of noise from signal in frequency domain

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, frequency

I have modeled noise in frequency domain(used matlab fft) and the the original signal also in frequency domain. I would like to adaptively subtract the model noise from the signal. I tried using wiener2, but it seems to work in pixels or i have no idea as it returns the input signal.Please inform which algorithm i used on matlab for adaptive subtraction in frequency domain?

Also a follow up question: the signal and noise is subband from 1 to 20 hz out of total of 250 hz. Although i have corrected for correct bin size. I need to confirm once i apply filter to 1 to 20 hz on the signal using noise model, do i need to replace these bins to the original full bins of the signal?
thanks

Comment: _"i have no idea as it returns the input signal."_ seems like the kernel that you are using with the `wiener2` filter is too small to have an effect on the image. Wiener is indeed the easiest filter to implement and understand for noise-reduction.

Comment: @JoeyMallone thanks. the matrix size of both the signal and noise is 3001x577. I used [m n]=[300 5]. also does wiener2 capable to take frequency domain inputs?

Comment: It does not, if you are using the `wiener2` built-in function. My apologies. I thought you had implemented an own 2d-`wiener` filter. The Matlab wiener2 works in the image-domain. More on that [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/wiener2.html).